# Useful techniques of experimental mathematics (reference request)

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, experimental-mathematics

I am searching for papers or books that explain thoroughly useful interesting techniques of *experimental mathematics* that can be understood and profitably applied by an undergraduate student.

Comment: You may wish to retag your question - there is a tag [experimental-mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/experimental-mathematics) here.

Comment: You may want to see [Implementing Reproducible Research by Victoria Stodden, Friedrich Leisch, Roger D. Peng](http://www.crcpress.com/product/isbn/9781466561595), which actually goes far beyond.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first two books reference each other, so I recommend having both on hand. The third is in my reading queue. All are by Jonathan Borwein and David Bailey.
[Experimentation in Mathematics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568811365)
[Mathematics by Experiment](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568814429)
[Experimental Mathematics in Action](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/156881271X)

Comment: These are very good suggestions. Thank you very much.