# A guide on how to approach learning programming

Tags: matlab, book-recommendation

I am going to take up an introductory course on computational mathematics this semester, in particular, to learn matlab.

We are given lecture notes and problem sheets to work through, however I was wondering if there existed any books which actually taught students how to approach learning something like this.

For example, something which guides the student on what to focus on when taking in all this new information.

I hope I have been clear enough in my request.

Comment: All of my programming knowledge comes from butchering other people's code.

Comment: Here is one option: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/962742/28555

Comment: @TheEmperorofIceCream, Can I order a filet of code?

Comment: Filet makes it sound like the process surgically selects the proper parts of code and then merges them into streamlined and efficient code. In real life the process renders code which is made up of chunks of good code that has been stitched together ungratefully. More like a chunky and ill-made hamburger. Although with time it improves.

Comment: What an intriguing suggestion. Did you trawl forums where people asked for help on matlab code and analyse things or was there some other approach

Comment: Those books use both _Matlab_ and _Mathematica_ for their examples.

Comment: @TheEmperorofIceCream, I'm sorry. I meant filet of cod.